# Trouble passing parameters in Prism-App (WPF)

Tags: wpf, navigation, parameter-passing, prism

In my prism application (WPF) I have a view model that passes parameters to another view model, let's call this MyViewModel. I have implemented the the BindableBase class and the INavigationAware interface. So my view model looks like this (simplified for the purpose of this question).

```
class MyViewModel : BindableBase, INavigationAware
{
    private IRegionManager _regionManager;
    private ObservableCollection<MyClass> _myClassCollection;
    private string _myParameter;
    private NavigationParameters _navigationParameters = new NavigationParameters();


    public ObservableCollection<MyClass> MyClassCollection => _myClassCollection;



    public MyViewModel(IRegionManager regionManager)
    {
        _regionManager = regionManager;

        _myClassCollection = GetMyClassData(_myParameter);
    }

    public void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationContext navigationContext)
    {
        _myParameter = navigationContext.Parameters.GetValue<string>("MyPassedParameter");
    }

    public bool IsNavigationTarget(NavigationContext navigationContext)
    {
        return false;
    }

    public void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationContext navigationContext)
    {

    }
}
```

I can see that the MyPassedParameter gets passed as expected in OnNavigatedTo method. The issue is, that the extract of the data - GetMyClassData - to be displayed in the corresponding view to this view model is depending on this parameter. Since the contructor runs before OnNavigatedTo, _myParameter has value null when I am using it in the constructor.

Can anybody tell me how I can use the passed parameter in the data extract for the view model.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there any reason why `GetMyClassData` _must_ be called in the constructor? If not, just move `_myClassCollection = GetMyClassData(_myParameter);` to the `OnNavigatedTo` method and call `RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(MyClassCollection))` or make it a property with backing filed and use `SetProperty(...)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you intend to set `_myClassCollection` to `GetMyClassData(_myParameter)`, it makes no sense to do this before you have gotten the `_myParameter` so you should move your initialization logic to the `OnNavigatedTo` method:

```
public MyViewModel(IRegionManager regionManager)
{
    _regionManager = regionManager;
}

public void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationContext navigationContext)
{
    _myParameter = navigationContext.Parameters.GetValue<string>("MyPassedParameter");
    _myClassCollection = GetMyClassData(_myParameter);
}
```

`_myParameter` is a navigation parameter that is not present by the time the view model is constructed.

Comment: Hi mm8. Thanks to you and all who contributed - much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> Since the contructor runs before OnNavigatedTo, _myParameter has value null when I am using it in the constructor.

This is a fundamental limitation of Prism's navigation concept. The view model locator creates the view model uninitialized, i.e. in an (otherwise) illegal state. It gets valid upon first navigation.

You can live with this and make your view model support the uninitialized state (e.g. drop get-only auto-properties) and load everything when you're navigated to.

Or you can drop Prism's navigation for this view model and create the view model yourself and link it to a data template ("view model first"). Earlier versions of Prism actually supported navigating to a view model (instead of the view), but you can always have a `ContentControl` bound to a property on the containing view model with a `DataTenmplate` to show the child view model.

Or you can create your own `RegionNavigationService` that supports creating a parametrized view model. See this [issue](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/issues/367) at github.